# How to change the JAVA_HOME from JRE to JDK on Amazon Web Services

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, java-8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, java

I use AWS (Amazon Web Services) elastic beanstalk and (Tomcat 8 - Java 8). By default is it a JRE used in Tomcat? I want to point to a JDK (I need to compile code).

I find documents on "ebextensions" but not work.

I am looking for a person who has done this. On my development environment (Eclipse), it works fine.

Comment: You need to compile code on your Elastic Beanstalk servers? What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: My application have a online IDE (with https://ace.c9.io). It's the same result of https://ideone.com but with specificities. I need compile the code from my online IDE. On my development environment (Eclipse), it works fine because I point to a JDK.